# When button is selected make tint color fill frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When a `UIButton` gets selected, how can I get it to select its full frame? Here is what I mean:

[image]

So the orange is the `UIButtons` frame, and the blue is when it's selected. How can I get the blue to fill the whole frame? (So you wouldn't see the orange.)

**Update**

[image]

Comment: on button click: button.frame = frame_of_orange_view

Comment: The orange is the buttons frame. It isn't another views frame

Comment: In what sense is the orange the button's frame? It looks to me like the blue is the button's frame and the orange is something else entirely.

Comment: I set a constraint to the button, that's why it's larger than the actual button text. But the orange is the button

Comment: Can you post a picture of the hierarchy of these two views? It's kinda fishy, no matter how we look at it, orange is a superview.

Comment: Are you setting an image when its selected?
Maybe that image has alpha on the sides?

Comment: No. I don't know why everyone is confused. Can you please try it, and make sure the buttons width is larger than the text? (Meaning, xcode will give a warning to make the buttons width smaller, so add a constraint, and in content make it selected, just like the image above.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the orange is the *superview* of the `UIButton` and that the *superview* is what you want to have the tint color applied to. If that's the case, then I would add a target to the button to change the superview's `backgroundColor` to match the `tintColor` of the button. Something like this should work:

```
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(setButtonSuperviewToTintColor:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then elsewhere in the controller add:

```
- (void)setButtonSuperviewToTintColor:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.superview.backgroundColor = sender.tintColor;
}
```

If the superview is *not* what you want to adjust, then create a method that changes the `UIButton`'s background color to it's tint color.

```
[myButton addTarget:self
             action:@selector(setButtonBackgroundColorToTintColor:)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and elsewhere:

```
- (void)setButtonBackgroundColorToTintColor:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.backgroundColor = sender.tintColor;
}
```

However, if you just want this to be the `selected` color, then there's kind of a method for this already. Unfortunately, it's designed to work with an image. But, making a color from an image is easy. So, this should work for you:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                               [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[myButton setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: In that case: button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

Comment: The orange is not the superview. It's the buttons background color